# how to list all post that are in the custom taxonomy using $wpdb

Tags: wpdb, sql

```
global $wpdb;

$custom_post_type = 'post'; // define your custom post type slug here

// A sql query to return all post titles
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s and post_status = 'publish' OR post_status ='draft' ", $custom_post_type ), ARRAY_A );
```

this will output all my post with publish and draft post

I'm trying to output post that are in the tag (tag1,tag2), adding these code to sql **tag_ID = 2 OR tag_ID = 1**

```
    "SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s and 
post_status = 'publish' and tag_ID = 2 OR tag_ID = 1 OR post_status ='draft' ", $custom_post_type ), ARRAY_A );
```

But it only return nothing?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `$wpdb` instead of `WP_Query`?

Comment: @JacobPeattie found an articile that $wpdb is much faster and uses low resource than wp_query, if i cant find any solution i might go with wp_query